# zone.js promise overwritten when deploy angular 2 (4) application on apache tomcat

Tags: angular-cli, angular2-aot

This are the versions I'm working with:

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.3
node: 6.9.2
os: win32 x64
@angular/common: 4.1.2
@angular/compiler: 4.1.2
@angular/core: 4.1.2
@angular/forms: 4.1.2
@angular/http: 4.1.2
@angular/platform-browser: 4.1.2
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.1.2
@angular/router: 4.1.2
@angular/cli: 1.0.3
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.1.2
Windows 7
```

#### Repro steps.

1.-
ng new myproject
cd myproject
ng build prod

2.-
Copy the content on dist on the WebContent of a java web project
Deploy the app on a tomcat server.
Open the app on a browser.**

#### The log given by the failure.

I used to render my angular2 application (compiled by the cli command ng build --prod -aot ) with no problems on a tomcat server.

Now, I would like to upgrade to angular to 4 and the cli to 1.

This is the **package.json** of a the new empty project I'd like to deploy in production server.

```
{   "name": "newproject",   "version": "0.0.0",   "license": "MIT",   "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"   },   "private": true,   "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    **"zone.js": "^0.8.4"**   },   "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"   } }
```

Here the **angular-cli.json**:

```
{   "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",   "project": {
    "name": "newproject"   },   "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }   ],   "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }   },   "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }   ],   "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }   },   "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}   } }
```

#### Desired functionality.

I would like the app works! message be shown on screen. Instead I see the "loading..." message and the follow error trace in console :

**- In Chrome 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit):**

> Unhandled promise rejection Error: Zone.js has detected that ZoneAwarePromise `(window|global).Promise` has been overwritten.
>   Most likely cause is that a Promise polyfill has been loaded after Zone.js (Polyfilling Promise api is not necessary when zone.js is loaded. If you must load one, do so before loading zone.js.)
>       at Function.Zone.assertZonePatched (zone.js:44)
>       at new NgZone (core.es5.js:3952)
>       at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleFactoryWithZone (core.es5.js:4746)
>       at core.es5.js:4790
>       at l (bundle.js:2)
>       at bundle.js:2
>       at MutationObserver.a (bundle.js:2)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:381)
>       at Zone.runGuarded (zone.js:154)
>       at MutationObserver. (zone.js:132)

- In Firefox 53.0.2 (32-bit):

> `Unhandled promise rejection Error: Zone.js has detected that ZoneAwarePromise`(window|global).Promise`has been overwritten.
>   Most likely cause is that a Promise polyfill has been loaded after Zone.js (Polyfilling Promise api is not necessary when zone.js is loaded. If you must load one, do so before loading zone.js.)
>   Traza de la pila:
>   Zone.assertZonePatched@http://localhost:8040/production/polyfills.bundle.js:2600:23
>   NgZone@http://localhost:8040/production/vendor.bundle.js:4315:9
>   PlatformRef_.prototype._bootstrapModuleFactoryWithZone@http://localhost:8040/production/vendor.bundle.js:5109:22
>   PlatformRef_.prototype._bootstrapModuleWithZone/<@http://localhost:8040/production/vendor.bundle.js:5153:53
>   l@http://127.0.0.1:51349/codelive-assets/bundle.js:2:18437
>   D/<@http://127.0.0.1:51349/codelive-assets/bundle.js:2:18559
>   a@http://127.0.0.1:51349/codelive-assets/bundle.js:2:22691
>   ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:8040/production/polyfills.bundle.js:2937:17
>   Zone.prototype.runGuarded@http://localhost:8040/production/polyfills.bundle.js:2710:28
>   Zone.prototype.wrap/<@http://localhost:8040/production/polyfills.bundle.js:2688:24`

#### Mention any other details that might be useful.

Googling on internet I've seen that It could be a problem with zone.js
I add the follow files that could be interesting in order to find out the bug.

**main.ts**

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**polyfills.ts**

```
/**
 * This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
 * You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
 *
 * This file is divided into 2 sections:
 *   1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are sorted by browsers.
 *   2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be loaded before your main
 *      file.
 *
 * The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that
 * automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera),
 * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
 *
 * Learn more in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
// import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
// import 'core-js/es6/object';
// import 'core-js/es6/function';
// import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
// import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
// import 'core-js/es6/number';
// import 'core-js/es6/math';
// import 'core-js/es6/string';
// import 'core-js/es6/date';
// import 'core-js/es6/array';
// import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
// import 'core-js/es6/map';
// import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
// import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following to support `@angular/animation`. */
// import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.


/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';


/** ALL Firefox browsers require the following to support `@angular/animation`. **/
// import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.



/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.



/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */

/**
 * Date, currency, decimal and percent pipes.
 * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE11 and Safari 10
 */
// import 'intl';  // Run `npm install --save intl`.
```

Comment: I have the same problem in 2019. How did you fix it?

Comment: I'm having the same problem as well in Angular 8 on two separate Angular projects. Anyone figure this out? Seems like it's been happening for years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create a project with the follow versions:

````
```
@angular/cli: 1.0.6
node: 6.9.2
os: win32 x64
@angular/common: 4.1.3
@angular/compiler: 4.1.3
@angular/core: 4.1.3
@angular/forms: 4.1.3
@angular/http: 4.1.3
@angular/platform-browser: 4.1.3
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.1.3
@angular/router: 4.1.3
@angular/cli: 1.0.6
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.1.3
```
````

1.- ng new a4project
2.- cd a4project
3.- ng build --prod
4.- Copy content of a4project/dist to javaA4Project/WebContent/
5.- Create the war file using maven clean install
6.- Copy a4Project to apache-tomcat-7/webapps/
7.- Start server

The application is rendered on web with no problems with zone.js.